# Configuring Apache Flink Local Set up with Pseudo distributed Yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I have set up HADOOP 2.8.3 and YARN on my Mac machine in Pseudo distributed mode, following this blog: [Hadoop in Pseudo Distributed Mode](http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html)
I have been able to successfully start hdfs and yarn. And also able to submit Map reduce jobs.

After that I have download Apache Flink 1.4 from [here](http://redrockdigimark.com/apachemirror/flink/flink-1.4.0/flink-1.4.0-bin-hadoop28-scala_2.11.tgz).
Now I am trying to set up Flink on the above Yarn cluster by following the steps [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/yarn_setup.html).
When I try to run /bin/yarn-session.sh -n 4 -jm 1024 -tm 4096, I am getting below error which I am unable to resolve. Can someone please advise and help me with the same?
`Error while deploying YARN cluster: Couldn't deploy Yarn session cluster
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't deploy Yarn session cluster
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deploySessionCluster(AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.java:372)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.run(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:679)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli$1.call(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:514)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli$1.call(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:511)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1807)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.main(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:511)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException: The number of virtual cores per node were configured with 1 but Yarn only has -1 virtual cores available. Please note that the number of virtual cores is set to the number of task slots by default unless configured in the Flink config with 'yarn.containers.vcores.'
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.isReadyForDeployment(AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deployInternal(AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.java:415)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.deploySessionCluster(AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor.java:367)`

Comment: Yep, the same error like in my case :-( . Could be a bug in 1.4 Flink version ?

Comment: yes, it seems that there is a bug...in Flink 1.3.2 it is working perfect !

Comment: Yes, I also just tried with 1.3.2, it works, however I am constrained to use 1.4.0 and need to get this working :-(

Comment: Ok, It started working for me after I added below configuration to yarn-site.xml:`<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>8</value>
  </property>`